# ViewPager showing Scrolling issue inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView has 2 type of ViewHolder inside it, one whose parent layout is CardView and another one is ViewPager. My issue is that when RecyclerView scrolls vertically, its stops scroll at ViewPager and can't scroll further on touching ViewPager. If i try to scroll on CardView row it works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947226/viewpager-showing-scrolling-issue-inside-recyclerview

Comment: Why don't you using horizontal RecyclerView instead of ViewPager. I know it will work.

Comment: i want swiping view, with automatic auto scroll

Comment: @BincyBaby found the solution?